# python - slow saving big files into the database

Tags: python, xml, postgresql

I have to parse data from XML files and each file has over 170k lines. The structure is following:

```
<el1>
    <el2>
        <el3>
            <el3-1>...</el3-1>
            <el3-2>...</el3-2>
        </el3>
        <el4>
            <el4-1>...</el4-1>
            <el4-2>...</el4-2>
        </el4>
        <el5>
            <el5-1>...</el4-1>
            <el5-2>...</el5-2>
        </el5>
    </el2>
</el1>
```

Basically I need to save attributes from the "el" tags and each tag represents a table in the database. So I get the values from attributes in el1 and insert them to the table etc.. The thing is, there is a lot of tags el3, el4, el5,... and I think when I call INSERT after each of them, it slows down the whole process because 1 file takes about 3 minutes to be saved into the database.

I thought I can solve this by saving the values into the list and when the file is processed, I run 1 INSERT command to save all values. But the problem is before I do the INSERT command, I select the last inserted id from the previous element and put it into the INSERT command in the next element as his foreign key. If I want to save values into the list, I can't get the last id from the database becase the insert will happen at the end of file.

I don't know if the whole process is slowed down because of the big amounts of INSERT commands, this is just my guess.

Comment: "slow" is relative, and you don't five much information. For such data, I think the first method should still be the best: keep it simple. But how do you read xml (and which module did you use), how to you insert rows, how do you have configurated postgresql, etc. Such question have huge impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done that, run all the `INSERT` statements in a single transaction, that makes a big difference.

For a better answer, provide more data, like your code, your system and how many transactions per second you are reaching.

Comment: you are right, i had commit() function after every INSERT statement.. I thought it won't save the data if there is no commit() after INSERT because i didn't see any changes in the database, but actually the data are saved at once after the file is processed if the commit() is just at the end of the script.. thanks